# Magento 2 - Quantity Field add on Up-Sell Products Listing product details page

Tags: magento2.1.5

I want to be able to add a quantity box to the products that show up in the 'Up-Sell products' list that is shown on the product detail page

Comment: Try to rewrite your question, and explain better what you have and what you need

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143961/how-to-add-multiple-products-to-a-cart-in-related-products-grid-on-product-detai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this code working for me.

> app/design/frontend/Theme/theme_child/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/upsell.phtml

```
<?php
   /**
    * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */

   // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

   /* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct */
   ?>
<?php
   switch ($type = $block->getType()) {



        case 'upsell':
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell $block */
            if ($exist = count($block->getItemCollection()->getItems())) {
                $type = 'upsell';
                $class = $type;

                $image = 'upsell_products_list';
                $title = __('Recommended Product Upsell');
                $items = $block->getItemCollection()->getItems();
                $limit = $block->getItemLimit('upsell');
                $shuffle = 0;

                $showWishlist = true;
                $showCompare = true;
                $showCart = true;
                $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::DEFAULT_VIEW;
                $description = false;
                $canItemsAddToCart = false;
            }
            break;

       case 'other':
       break;
   }
   ?>
<?php if ($exist):?>
<?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'): ?>
<?php if ($type == 'upsell'): ?>
<div class="block <?php echo $class; ?>" data-mage-init='{"relatedProducts":{"relatedCheckbox":".related.checkbox"}}' data-limit="<?php echo $limit; ?>" data-shuffle="<?php echo $shuffle; ?>">
<?php else: ?>
<div class="block <?php echo $class; ?>" data-mage-init='{"upsellProducts":{}}' data-limit="<?php echo $limit; ?>" data-shuffle="<?php echo $shuffle; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="block <?php echo $class; ?>">
   <?php endif; ?>
    <header class='group-title1'><h2><?php echo $title;?> </h2></header>

    <div class="block-content content" aria-labelledby="block-<?php echo $class?>-heading"> 
        <div class="owl-container">
            <div id="upsell_product_slider" class="owl-carousel">
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                <?php 
                    $i = 0;
                    $rows = 1;
                    echo count($items);
                ?>
                <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                <?php $available = ''; ?>  
                <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_item, $image);
                ?>
                    <?php if ($i++%$rows==0) { ?>
                    <div class="item">
                    <?php } ?>
                        <div class="item-inner">
                            <div class="image-container">
                                <a href="<?php echo $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product-item-photo">
                                    <?php echo $productImage->toHtml() ?>
                                </a>
                                <!--div class="box-hover">

                                </div-->
                            </div>

                            <div class="product details box-info">
                                <div class="name-rating">
                                    <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a class="product-item-link" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" href="<?php echo $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                                    </strong>
                                    <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                        <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType,true); ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>

                                <?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_item); ?>

                            </div>

                            <?php if ($showCart): ?>

                                <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                    <form  data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item); ?>" method="post">
                                        <div style="float: left;">
                                            <input type="number"
                                                   name="qty"
                                                   style="width:50px;"
                                                   maxlength="12"
                                                   value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                                                   title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                                                   data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                                                   />

                                            <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>

                                            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>" class="action tocart primary" style="float:right;margin-left: 10px;">
                                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Add to Cart'); ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>

                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php if($i%$rows==0 || $i == count($items)) { ?> 
                    </div> 
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
<?php endif;?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   require(["jquery"], function($){

      $("#upsell_product_slider").owlCarousel({
        items : 4,
        itemsDesktop : [1200,3],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [992,3],
        itemsTablet: [767,2],
        itemsMobile : [400,1],
        autoPlay : true,
        slideSpeed : 3000,
        navigation : true,
        stopOnHover : true,
        pagination : true,
        pagination : true 
      });

   });
</script>
```

Comment: This will not working when product have "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" and "Qty Increments" settings.