# Magento : Add product qty box in related product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, related-products

I have a related product list in product detail page. Default there is not qty box available to edit qty i want to add qty box and also it's qty add to checkout/cart page while add specific qty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first add qty field in related_product.phtml file then rewrite function `public function addAction()` in file `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php`

> in this method related products are added just by their ids as shown
>   below-

```
$related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');
/**
 * Check product availability
 */
 if (!$product) {
     $this->_goBack();
     return;
 }

 $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
 if (!empty($related)) {
          $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
 }
```

> and here you need to do something like this- Using Fix Quantity :

```
if (!empty($related)) {
           foreach (explode(',', $related) as $productId) {
              $rp = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
              $rparams['qty'] = 2; // desired quantity got from frontend
              $cart->addProduct($rp, $rparams);
           }

               // $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
  }
```

> and here you need to do something like this- Using User Entered Quantity :

```
if (!empty($related)) {
            foreach (explode(',', $related) as $productId) {                    
                $rp = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);                  
                $rparams['qty'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_qty_'.$productId); // desired quantity got from frontend
                $cart->addProduct($rp, $rparams);
            }
            //$cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
        }       

and here 'related_qty_'.$productId is quantity textbox name.
```

above is a basic idea to achieve goal.

please comment if it does not work.

Comment: Thanks Shashank, It is working fine but i want dynamic qty of related product so how to get it.?

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you have go through below link to achieve your all things.

1. [Quantity Field on Related Products Listing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123848/magento-2-quantity-field-on-related-products-listing)
2. [Quantity Field on Related Products Cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143961/how-to-add-multiple-products-to-a-cart-in-related-products-grid-on-product-detai)

I hope it will help to you.